# Find command doesn't work for certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, find

I just downloaded some source code from a repository and I'm trying to locate a specific file in it. For simplicity, assume that the entire project has the following directory hierarchy

```
        project
       /       \ 
    src          docs
   /    \             \
other    test2.h        test1.h
```

I navigate to the project directory and then use the following command

```
sudo find . -name test1.h
```

This works perfectly.

However, the following command doesn't work:

```
sudo find . -name test2.h
```

The find command is able to locate test1.h but not test2.h.  Why could this be? Is it possible for one of the folders to be non-searchable?

Note, I'm doing all of this on a linux machine

Comment: Is it a public accessible repository? If so, can you give the URL and the file which is working and the one which isn't?! Can you `cd` into the dir which contains `test2.h`?

Comment: Is `find.` (missing space) a typo in the second command?

Comment: @mpy, no unfortunately it is not a public repository, thus I can't give you the URL...Also, I can cd into the dir that contains test2.h and then, in that case, the `find` command works

Comment: @find Yes, that is just a typo, I'll fix that

Comment: Is src a symbolic link? If so you'll need `-L`

Comment: I'm not sure...What is a symbolic link?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `r` or `x` access on `src` directory.